# "Комиссия" как ругательство

Tags: значение-слов

"Вошел я в вокзал: гляжу — сидит он у книжного ящика с каким-то морским офицером. Ах ты комиссия! Бросил он обедать, познакомил нас с офицером", — пишет Михаил Чехов о брате.

Собственно, откуда у такого выражения ноги растут? Почему им можно обругать? Да и использовалось ли это слово где-либо ещё подобным образом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это отнюдь не ругательство. 
Комиссия - хлопоты, затруднения, несчастный случай.
В современном языке это значение используется только иронически (да и то устаревает), раньше было вполне в ходу. У Чехова это сказано с сожалением, но совсем не как ругательство.

У Грибоедова примешивается раздражение, но опять-таки без тени ругательства.

*Что за комиссия, Создатель,

Быть взрослой дочери отцом!*

Собственно, на этом последнем примере все обычно и знакомятся с этим значением.

Comment: И комиссары в пыльных шлемах склонятся молча надо мной.

Comment: А вот комиссар - это от другого значения. Вполне ныне живого.